# How do I backup my Wubi install? Hoping to resize, add new partition, and move away from Wubi

Tags: grub2, wubi, bootloader

My Wubi install is near ~22GB, I have an external hard drive with that amount of free space and SOOOO much more.

What I want to do is be able to install everything exactly as it is now, or as close as it is now, with as little hassle as possible, but saving things such as sources, current files in my directors, and POSSIBLY even my settings and wms. How would I go about doing this?

Also, how would I go about NOT defaulting to the GRUB bootloader. I'd very much prefer to keep what I have now.

Comment: I recommend posting your GRUB question separately.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!